# How to re-render component after BACK button using stacknavigator in RN

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

BACK button is not generating props or state change in thecomponent so it wont re-render.

My Flow:

```
Home 
  => SomeView(prop id:1) 
    => SomeView(prop id: 7) 
      => SomeView(prop id: 1)
```

Pressing back button does notany effect in the views though stack is going back properly and titles of each view are changing too.

My component text onClick is calling `navigate('SomeView',{props})`.

Plz suggest how to achieve re-render.

Comment: What is the reason for re-rendering the view?

Comment: the props of the view are not changing by back button

Comment: You are not answering my question. I will re-phrase. What the user do in "SomeView(prop id:1)" do that SomeView(prop id: 7) have to be re-rendered?